# Can someone explain the concept of Shapley value masking when working with tabular data and classification problems?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection, importance, shapley-value

My understanding of a mask in arrays is to have boolean values matching the shape of a query array (n, m) where you would mask the query and perform an operation. For example, this operation to sum only the positive values in an array:

```py
import numpy as np
query = np.random.normal(size=(5,10))
mask = query > 0
np.sum(query[mask], axis=1)
```

1. Is the concept of masking in `SHAP` similar, the same, or completely different? I'm talking exclusively about tabular data.
2. How do you decide on a mask to make the process reproducible and not subjective?

Let's say you have the following conditions:

```
* Binary classification: Healthy, Disease
* Multiclass classification: Healthy, Disease_A, Disease_B (mutually exclusive, can only be one per sample)
```

3. In a lot of the examples, they are masking a training set and then calculating SHAP values on the test set.  This seems to be dependent on the random seed.  Would it be better to use cross-validation and calculate a distribution of SHAP values per feature?

For example, like this:

```py
for training_index, testing_index in KFold(n_splits=3, random_state=0, shuffle=True).split(X, y):
    X_training = X.iloc[training_index]
    X_testing = X.iloc[testing_index]
    explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(clf.predict_proba, X_training)
    shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_testing)
```

4. Last question, how can I calculate a "final" SHAP value for my dataset given all of the data?  Either a single vector that has the total predictive capacity of a feature or an array (m features, c classes).

Comment: What do you mean by making the process reproducible? What do you mean by "final SHAP value"? Do you mean a global average for the model?

Answer (score 1):

1. ML Models usually accept inputs with fixed number of features: If model was trained on 10 features, it is impossible to provide a point where only 7 features are defined.

SHAP operates on a different coalition of features, so to compute a feature importance (SHAP value) for feature f1, it checks what model predicts if only f1 defined, if (f1, f2) are defined, (f1, f3) and so on, (see how [Shapley Values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapley_value) are defined for more information).
As I mentioned for ML models absent features still must be defined somehow. zero, NaN or any other values can used for example, but such values may produce out-of-distribution samples: if the model have never seen zero for a feature it may go crazy. To cope with that a masker/background dataset can be used. Suppose there is a point $x$, and we need to evaluate model on features $f_1, f_2$, and "ignore" features $f_3, f_4$. To do that the absent features are substituted with every points from the masker dataset, and we have a new dataset $D$ with the same size as masker dataset where $f_1, f_2$ features are always the same and equal $x$, and $f_3, f_4$ equal to masker dataset. Then we evaluate model on $D$ and take the average.

3. I think is a good idea to cross-validate it on training (masker) dataset, for training dataset it depends if local or global Shapley values should be obtained
4. If "final" is a global shapley values -- average shapley values for different point is a standard solution.